# Single-Parenting Behaviour for DriveApp Methods

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

My understanding is that placing a file in multiple parent folders is no longer allowed on Drive (per the announcement of the single-parent model).

Using Google Apps Script methods (specifically DriveApp methods) to find the parent of a file, it seems I still have to obtain a folder iterator first using *file*.getParents().  Then use the folder iterator to find the parent folder.

Is this correct?  I don't understand why there isn't a *file*.getParent() method now that would directly provide the parent folder.

Comment: what have you tried?  how does it work?

Comment: @Cooper getParents() still works just the same with FileIterator

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is correct. Currently, There isn't a `file.getParent()` method to directly get  the parent `Folder`. You can create a [feature request here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).

Comment: Have you found a source saying that getParents() will continue to be used? I'm surprised it is not marked deprecated.

Comment: @Trigaten Bunch of methods were [deprecated during this change](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#july_27_2020). But this wasn't one of them